# How do I setup lets encrypt for an Azure Linux Service Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, lets-encrypt

I have found plenty of guides on how to set up Lets Encrypt for Azure **Windows** Web App Services, but I can't find any at all for **Linux** based services.

Here are two example of such tutorials (that require windows).

- https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SecuringAnAzureAppServiceWebsiteUnderSSLInMinutesWithLetsEncrypt.aspx
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6V_mBo-gnE

In the tutorials above, and all other tutorials I have found you need to use Web App **Extensions** to do the actual updating of the cert every 3 months. But these are **not available on Linux apps**.

This is all you see in the Azure portal when you try to navigate to it.

[image: no extension for you]

So, does anyone have any links, or helpful tips on **how to set up automated Let's encrypt certificates for Azure Linux Services?**

I'm sure people would want Lets Encrypt for Linux apps as well?

Answer (score 4):

You could [set up a Let's Encrypt SSL Cert for Azure Web App with Linux in 5 steps](https://jessicadeen.com/how-to-manually-setup-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-cert-for-azure-web-app-with-linux/).

1. Install Certbot client
2. Create Let's Encrypt Cert with Certbot (Manually)
3. Convert PEM to PFX for Azure using OpenSSL

   `openssl pkcs12 -inkey /work-dir-path/live/website.com/privkey.pem -in /work-dir-path/live/website.com/cert.pem -export -out /work-dir-path/live/website.com/cert.pfx`
4. Upload PFX cert to Azure Portal with Azure CLI method

   `az webapp config hostname add --webapp-name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup \ --hostname $fqdn`

   `thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file $pfxPath \ --certificate-password $pfxPassword --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup \ --query thumbprint --output tsv)`
5. Bind uploaded SSL certificate to your webapp Portal with Azure CLI method

   `az webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint $thumbprint --ssl-type SNI \ --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup`

Alternatively, Azure lets you create a free certificate and add it your App Service app at the click of a couple buttons. It's issued by `DigiCert`, managed by App Service, and renewed automatically. See [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview).

Comment: This will not automatically renew the certificate will it ?

Comment: I noticed the free cert in Azure as well, I think that might be my best alternative. Unfortunately they dont support subdomains, but that might be a small price to pay for simplicity

Comment: The best will be the free App Service Managed Certificate and it could renew automatically.

Comment: Do you still have any questions?

Comment: No, I understand your answer, This requires me to manually renew the letsencrypt certificata every 3 months, or use the MS certificate, but their certificate is quite limited in what it allowed. Neither solution is very good (but that's not your fault). I was hoping someone might come along with a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 3):

I found a very good solution to this issue recently. You can use the [let's encrypt web app renewer](https://github.com/ohadschn/letsencrypt-webapp-renewer) to install and renew your certificates for the Linux Web Apps.

1. Create a free app plan for windows
2. Create a web app for windows
3. Follow the instructions on the Github page - set it up to renew the linux web app certs (as many as you want)
4. Schedule a job to hit the webook or use a azure function or any other option to trigger the job every 3 months.

There are a few tricks to getting it working correctly with .net core on linux especially if you are using spa services. I had to set the letsencrypt:webAppName-webRootPath configuretion to d:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot because of the spa static files.

Done!

Comment: Just a note about that last part to web root, that will depend on which runtime you're using. The path is correct if you're running ASP.NET Core, but if you're running a node app, for example, and you're straight up serving files, it wouldn't be in the subfolder wwwroot.